# Retrieve data from url and save in php

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to retrieve the html from file get contents in php then save it to a php file so I can include it into my homepage.

Unfortunately my script isn't saving the data into the file. I also need to verwrite this data on a daily basis as it will be setup with a cron job.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong please? I am just learning php :-)

```
<?php 
$richSnippets = file_get_contents('http://website.com/data');
$filename = 'reviews.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename,"x+");
$somecontent = echo $richSnippets;
fwrite($handle,$somecontent);
echo "Success";
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: and you're sure that `allow_url_fopen` has been enabled in your php.ini, amongst other things?

Comment: I am sure, the file is being written.

Comment: `$somecontent = echo $richSnippets;` => `$somecontent = $richSnippets;`

Comment: You're misunderstanding me. The local file, `reviews.txt`, can be opened without issues because it's using the local file system pointer. However, the `page` you're trying to open requires an `http stream wrapper`, which is generally disabled on things like shared hosting, or fresh WAMP installations.

Comment: just use wget in your crontab

Comment: Ah. Is there any way to workaround?

Comment: `allow_url_fopen = On` in your `php.ini` file. Also, do what @djidi said as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of things,

`http://website.com/data` gets a 404 error, it doesn't exist.

Change your code to

```
$site = 'http://www.google.com';
$homepage = file_get_contents($site);
$filename = 'reviews.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename,"w");
fwrite($handle,$homepage);
echo "Success";
fclose($handle);
```

Remove `$somecontent = echo $richSnippets;` it doesn't do anything.

if you have the proper permissions it should work.

Be sure that your pointing to an existing webpage.

**Edit**

When cURL is enabled you can use the following function

```
function get_web_page( $url ){
  $options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
  );

  $ch      = curl_init( $url );
  curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
  $content = curl_exec( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );

  return $content;
}
```

Now change

```
$homepage = file_get_contents($site);
```

in to

```
$homepage = get_web_page($site);
```

Comment: Hi @wezy, the url was just to illustrate. I think as we have shared hosting fopen is not allowed :-(

Comment: @matthew Can you see if cURL is enbaled

Comment: @matthew Added a cURL function to my answer

Comment: I have tried your solution with below url, but your solution does not work. https://www.instagram.com/nasa/?__a=1

Answer (score 0):

You should use **/** instead of ****

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://website.com/data');
```

Also this part

```
$somecontent = echo $richSnippets;
```

I don't see $richSnippets above... it's probably not declared?

You probably want to do this:

```
fwrite($handle,$homepage);
```

Comment: Why don't you use file_put_contents() ?

Comment: how would I save this data in file_put_contents() please?

Comment: use file_get_contents(url) to GET the data and file_put_contents($file, $data) to save to file

Comment: I have tried your solution with below url, but your solution does not work. https://www.instagram.com/nasa/?__a=1 Getting blank in $homepage variable when i echo the output. Any other suggestion.